Dynamically create and display ipywidgets, failing in databricks notebook
Goal: An array of ipywidgets, that can be extended through a button-click on the UI.
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

# Keeps track of default and dynamically added widgets
widgets_list = [widgets.Text(value='Give me')]

w_out_widgets_list = widgets.Output()
# display defaults
w_out_widgets_list.append_display_data(widgets.HBox(widgets_list))  

def add_new_widget(b):
    with w_out_widgets_list:
        widgets_list.append(widgets.Text(value='more and '))
        w_out_widgets_list.clear_output()
        display(widgets.HBox(widgets_list))

w_new_widget = widgets.Button(description='Add Widget')
w_new_widget.on_click(add_new_widget)

display(widgets.VBox([w_out_widgets_list, w_new_widget]))

This is working as expected in my locally running jupyter notebook.
Within the databricks notebook, a strange behaviour is observable:

Default widget creation works fine
Button click appends a widget to the widget_list, but does not update the displayed widgets.
Upon a second click, the view updates by displaying the now three widgets below the default one.


ipywidgets are on version 7.7.2 there.
Any ideas on what the cause of this behavior is?

Please add something like ',failing in databricks notebook' to your title to make this follow the section 'Write a title that summarizes the specific problem' in How do I ask a good question?. Your code definitely works with ipywidgets 8.0.2. Does the example with button.on_click(on_button_clicked) here work in Databricks for you? Definitely odd but not seeing how to fix easily since not consistent with newer things and so expectedly an update would be all that is needed. Maybe ...

 for now just comment in instructions to user that it can take a couple times to get it to work, but maybe you don't want it displaying more than two?

Thanks @Wayne. I was not sure, whether the approach was not clean and just coincidentally running locally. From your response I am reading, that the issue is rather environment related and I am not fundamentally abusing/misusing functionality of ipywidgets.
The linked example is working.
I tried to break the problem down to a more concise form. The effective problem might require 5+ widgets.

I definitely think you are using good code. It is odd that it is glitchy in that old ipywidgets. I don't have an old version handy to test in to really say if it is that or something unusual about datbricks.

My guess is, that the identification of currently active widget Output varied from databricks to local Jupyter Notebook.
Wrapping the functionality in a class allows to recreate the expected behavior within databricks, too:
import ipywidgets as widgets


class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.widgets_list = [widgets.Text(value="Give me")]
        self.w_new_widget = widgets.Button(description="Add Widget")
        self.w_new_widget.on_click(self.add_new_widget)
        self.app_out = widgets.Output()
        self.generate_layout()

    def generate_layout(self):
        self.app_out.clear_output()
        with self.app_out:
            display(widgets.VBox([widgets.HBox(self.widgets_list),
                                  self.w_new_widget]))

    def add_new_widget(self, *args):
        self.widgets_list.append(widgets.Text(value="more and "))
        self.generate_layout()


app = App()
display(app.app_out)

